# Pygame sprite creating duplicate instead of moving

Tags: python, pygame

I am fairly new to Pygame.

I am attempting to re-create Pong in Python using Pygame, but I have hit a roadblock.

Here is my code:

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
UP = "up"
DOWN = "down"
white = (255,255,255)
black = (0,0,0)
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)

resolution = (800,600)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong!")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()


running = True


class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((25,100))
        self.image.fill(white)

        pygame.draw.rect(self.image,white, (0,0,25,100))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self,direction,pixels):
        if direction == DOWN:
            self.rect.y -= pixels
        if direction == UP:
            self.rect.y += pixels

player1 = Paddle()

player1.rect.x = 0
player1.rect.y = 200



sprites_list.add(player1)

while running:


    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player1.move(DOWN, 5)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player1.move(UP, 5)

    sprites_list.update()

    sprites_list.draw(window)


    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

I am trying to make player1, a Paddle object, move up or down depending on which key is pressed. When I run this code, player1 is stretched out after the up or down arrows are pressed; 5 pixels are added onto player1.rect.

What am I doing wrong and why will sprites_list.update() not put player1 in its new position?

Comment: you have to clear screen before you draw new element in loop - ie. fill with black color `window.fill( (0,0,0) )`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to clear screen before you draw elements in new loop.
You can fill window with black color `window.fill((0,0,0))` or draw background image in every loop.

This is your code after reorganization and adding `window.fill(BLACK)`

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)

UP = "up"
DOWN = "down"

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

# --- classes ---- (CamelCaseNames)

class Paddle(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface((25,100))
        self.image.fill(WHITE)

        # you don't have to draw white rect if all surface already is white
        #pygame.draw.rect(self.image,white, (0,0,25,100))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def move(self, direction, pixels):
        if direction == DOWN:
            self.rect.y += pixels
        if direction == UP:
            self.rect.y -= pixels

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# empty

# --- main --- (lower_case_names)

# - init -

pygame.init()
pygame.mouse.set_visible(True)
window = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong!")

# - objects -

sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

player1 = Paddle()
player1.rect.x = 0
player1.rect.y = 200

sprites_list.add(player1)

# - mainloop -

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True

while running:

    # - events -

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        player1.move(DOWN, 5)
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        player1.move(UP, 5)

    # - updates (without draws) -

    sprites_list.update()

    # - draws (without updates) -

    window.fill(BLACK) # <--- clear screen 

    sprites_list.draw(window)

    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(60)

# - end -

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: Thank you. I understand this to reset the screen. What is the purpose of sprites_list.update()? Is it needed if I include sprites_list.draw()?

Comment: `sprites_list.update()` executes method `update()` in every object which can change `x`, `y` or other things (like select next frame of animation) but not to draw, `sprites_list.draw()` does  `screen.blit(self.rect, self.image) for every object so it only draws objects. Between `sprites_list.update()` and  `sprites_list.draw()` you can have other functions - ie. you can check collisions.

Comment: Took me hours trying to figure it out before I found this great answer. The problem was, I had all the necessary methods: fill, draw, update, and flip, but in wrong order, so whoever stumbles upon this answer just remember, the order matters